# SharePoint 2010 Search Query

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

I had written a custom search query for MOSS 2007 to get data where contenttype is post. However the same query is not returning any results in SharePoint 2010. Any inputs will be appreciated.

Please note that SharePoint search box is returning (parameter k in query string and also contenttype:post) appropriate results.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi David, thanks.The query looks like this:

SELECT TOP 3 title,path,author body   FROM scope()   WHERE  (contenttype = 'post' ) AND (path like '<site url>')

Comment: All,
An update to this.The query is running fine if i remove the like clause. 
For example: SELECT title,body,author,path from scope() where contenttype='post' works perfect.

But when i add like condition:
SELECT title,body,author,path from scope() where contenttype='post' and title like 'MyBlog%'
does not return any results though there are many blogs starting with MyyBlog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get this issue resolved. I've got a similar issue

The following worked

SELECT TOP 3 title,path,author body FROM scope() WHERE (contenttype = 'post' ) AND CONTAINS(path,'siteurl')

This didn't work (even though it should work)

SELECT TOP 3 title,path,author body FROM scope() WHERE (contenttype = 'post' ) AND CONTAINS(path,'siteur*')

Comment: Sorry for replying late, i had already tried that but was not sure as to why direct wild card should not work.Thanks anyways for the answer.

Comment: SELECT TOP 3 title,path,author body FROM scope() WHERE (contenttype = '' ) AND CONTAINS(path,'siteur*') in the query i passed content type as empty value. how the contion will work???

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT TOP 3 title,path,author body FROM scope() WHERE (contenttype = "post" ) AND CONTAINS(path,"siteur*")
```